# JDBCRealm unable to connect to datasource for authentification

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jdbcrealm

There already exists some questions about this topic but none of them were a solution to my problem. What I want to do is a basic login screen using a form based authentication in java EE on a glassfish server. Now the problem is that I allways get to the error page. Here is a log of the error I get:

```
    javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to connect to datasource jdbc/connectionPool for database user null.
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.getConnection(JDBCRealm.java:585)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.isUserValid(JDBCRealm.java:408)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:324)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule.authenticate(JDBCLoginModule.java:78)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:116)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.BasePasswordLoginModule.login(BasePasswordLoginModule.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:383)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:154)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:695)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:636)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/connectionPool' in SerialContext[myEnv={com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jndisuffix=__nontx, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: connectionPool not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.naming.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookup(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupNonTxResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:553)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupNonTxResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:538)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.getConnection(JDBCRealm.java:573)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: connectionPool not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 56 more

Précis:   JAAS authentication aborted.
Le plus précis:   doPasswordLogin fails
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Security Exception
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:840)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:383)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:154)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:695)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:636)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:841)
    ... 39 more
```

Here are some of my configurations:

glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<resources>
      <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/connectionPool" object-type="user" pool-name="connectionPool"/>
      <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="derby_net_TestProject_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" ping="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" pooling="true" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-cache-size="0" statement-leak-reclaim="false" statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TestProject"/>
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="1527"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="TestProject"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="root"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      </jdbc-connection-pool>
    </resources>
```

My Realm configuration:

[image: Realm config]

And the DB:

[image]

If I understand it correctly, my server is unable to connect to the datasource but I don't know why?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the derbyclient.jar file in the glassfish lib folder and restart the glassfish and now create your connection pool, then it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for the late response. I tried this but didn't fixed. Now instead of this error:

"""javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: connectionPool not found"""

 I got this one: 

"""javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation"""

Comment: i am unable to figure out the exact solution , please check out this link this may help https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Derby+with+Glassfish